# Problem in complex analysis involving Liouville's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $f$ bounded and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ ($a\neq b$). For $R>max(|a|,|b|)$ we have $I_{n}=\displaystyle\int_{|z|=R}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}dz$. Calculate $I_{n}$ and the limit $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}I_{n}$

- **My thoughts**

First I used Liouville's theorem since its bounded when  $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ so $f(z)\equiv constant$. Then I wrote that since $a,b\notin D(r,R)$ there are no anomalies in the Integral. So can i declare $\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ holomorphic in this Disc and say that the $I_{n}=0$?

Comment: Use `$\Bbb C$` for $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Is $f$ entire? If so, then say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the goal of the exercise is to *prove* Liouville's theorem. The residue if $\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ at $a$ and $b$ is $\frac{f(a)}{a-b}$ and $\frac{f(b)}{b-a}$ respectively. Therefore,$$I_n=2\pi i\left(\frac{f(a)}{a-b}+\frac{f(b)}{b-a}\right)=2\pi i\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$On the other hand, $\lim_{R\to+\infty}I_n=0$. Therefore$$(\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C}):f(a)=f(b),$$which means that $f$ is constant.

Comment: so would it be wrong to to start with Liouville's theorem and then prove that the integral and limit is 0?

Comment: Why would you think the goal is to prove Liouville when the OP already knows Liouville?

Comment: @Pookaros Not wrong, but a waste of time. It is very simple to prove that $\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_{|z|=R}\frac K{(z-a)(z-b)}=0$.

Comment: @zhw. Instinct.